# Count Letter Frequencies

Tags: java, arrays

The below code is from my old lecture notes and I have forgotten why do we need
        `letters[index]++` here? Can someone explain why do we need it?

```
public class CountLetterFrequencies {

    /* Private instance variables */
    private static int[] letters = new int[26];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This program counts letter frequencies. Enter text:");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String line = sc.nextLine(); 

        countLetterFrequencies(line);

        printFrequencyTable();

        sc.close();
    }

    /* Counts the letter frequencies in a line of text */
    private static void countLetterFrequencies(String line) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            char ch = line.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetter(ch)) { // Character.isLetter(ch)
                int index = Character.toUpperCase(ch) - 'A'; // index = C - A = 2
                letters[index]++;
            }
        }
    }

private static void printFrequencyTable() {
        for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++) {
            int index = ch - 'A'; // So, if ch is B, then index => B-A => 1
            if(letters[index] != 0) // if we wanna print only existing letters
                System.out.println(ch + ": " + letters[index]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I know it but why do we need it?

Comment: You need it because you are storing the letter counts in an array. the value of any element in the array contains the count and the index acts as a key for the letter used. For example - the counts of letter A is stored in `'A' -'A' = 0`

Comment: Just a sidenote: This implementation will happily break with an exception with 99% of all input where `Character.isLetter(ch)`returns `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int index = Character.toUpperCase(ch) - 'A';
```

`index` gives you the position in the array where the count for that particular is stored.

```
letters[index]++;
```

And then it increments the count of that particular character.

Understand this

```
 index = Character.toUpperCase(ch) - 'A';
```

- 'A' - 'A'    this will give array position 0
- 'B' - 'A' this will give array position 1 which is B count position and so on, till
- 'Z' - 'A' this will give position 25 of the array where the count of 'Z' will be stored

It does ASCII value subtraction

For

```
 'A' - 'A' it will do 65-65 =0    65 is ascii value of 'A'

 'B' - 'A' it will do 66-65 =1

 'Z' - 'A' it will do 90-65 = 25
```

Comment: I can't. My reputation is too low for that

Comment: Um, actually, it does UTF-16 code unit subtraction. This algorithm is designed for the Latin capital letters in the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block of the Unicode character set. Any other characters wouldn't work well (besides the Latin small letters in the same block).